# Relation involving max of gamma distributed random variables

Tags: probability

I'm trying to understand the following relation with random variables $\{\Gamma _n=E_1+...+E_n, n\ge 1\}$ where $\{E_n\}$ are iid unit exponential random variables.
$$\sqrt n\bigvee _{i=1}^n|\frac{i}{n}-\frac{\Gamma_i}{\Gamma _{n+1}}|
=\frac{n}{\Gamma _{n+1}}\bigvee _{i=1}^n|\frac{\Gamma _i -i}{\sqrt n}-\frac{i}{n}\frac{\Gamma_{n+1}-n}{\sqrt n}|\\$$

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Forget random variables - this is true for any sequence of non-negative numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}$. To see why this is true, we note that for $i=1,\ldots,n$ we have
$$
\frac{x_i-i}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{i}{n}\frac{x_{n+1}-n}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{i}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{i x_{n+1}}{n\sqrt{n}}+\frac{in}{n\sqrt{n}}=\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{i x_{n+1}}{n\sqrt{n}}.
$$
Using that $a\cdot \max\limits_i y_i=\max\limits_i (ay_i)$ we obtain
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{n}{x_{n+1}}\max_i\left|\frac{x_i-i}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{i}{n}\frac{x_{n+1}-n}{\sqrt{n}}\right|&=\sqrt{n}\max_i\left|\frac{\sqrt{n}}{x_{n+1}}\left(\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{i x_{n+1}}{n\sqrt{n}}\right)\right|\\
&=\sqrt{n}\max_i\left|\frac{x_i}{x_{n+1}}-\frac{i}{n}\right|\\
&=\sqrt{n}\max_i\left|\frac{i}{n}-\frac{x_i}{x_{n+1}}\right|.
\end{align}
$$